# Wait until infinite while loop is completed

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, synchronization

I have an infinite while loop which runs on another thread. In this while loop, I am using a String. For this String, I also have a setter. When someone calls the setter, I want it to wait until the current iteration of the while loop finished and change it for the next iteration.

This is what I tried:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Test {

    private String testString = "aaaaaaa";

    private Test() {
        new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                synchronized (testString) {
                    System.out.println(testString);

                    // Simulating a thread blocking operation
                    try {
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
                    } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
                        exception.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    System.out.println(testString);
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private void setTestString(String testString) {
        synchronized (testString) {
            this.testString = testString;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();

        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
        } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

        test.setTestString("bbbbbbbb");
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```
aaaaaaa
aaaaaaa
bbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbb
...
```

Actual output:

```
aaaaaaa
bbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbb
...
```

Why is not the `setTestString` method waiting? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In method `setTestString` and `Thread`, at both places you are trying to get the lock on string literal as sent from the calling place. so they are actually not the lock on same String object, if you are looking to do that. Can you check in that direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your thread is reading the updated instance variable every time. If you want the iteration of the loop see a consistent value, you should read the value of the instance variable only once. Also, since you are writing it from one thread and reading it from another, you need to make it volatile or do the read-write within synchronized methods.

```
private volatile String testString = "aaaaaaa";

private Test() {
    new Thread(() -> {
        while (true) {
                // volatile read
                String localTestString = testString;

                System.out.println(localTestString);

                // Simulating a thread blocking operation
                try {
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
                } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }

                System.out.println(localTestString);
        }
    }).start();
}
```

> When someone calls the setter, I want it to wait until the current iteration of the while loop finished

That is not a good solution. If you make the set method wait, there is no guarantee it gets scheduled after the current iteration of the loop is finished. You can see it for yourself: change the set method to

```
private void setTestString(String testString) {
    synchronized (this.testString) {
        this.testString = testString;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I tried it without making `testString` volatile and it still work. I guess the issue with that is that t is not reliable that way? Or why would it need to be volatile?

Comment: Without volatile it's unreliable. Imagine the main thread and the infinite loop get scheduled on different CPUs with separate caches - one thread does not automatically see what values the other thread sets. Lots of articles you can read about this e.g. https://www.baeldung.com/java-volatile